# Inject into ToMethod binding

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm not quite sure how to ask this so I'll just post my code sample and give a brief description of what I'm trying to do. I have the following bindings setup:

```
kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<FormsAuthenticationService>();
kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationService>().To<TokenAuthenticationService>().When(r => HasAncestorOfType<MyWebApiController>(r));
```

Here's the code for HasAncestorOfType (although I think it's irrelevant here):

```
private static bool HasAncestorOfType<T>(IRequest request)
{
    if (request.Target == null)
        return false;

    if (request.Target.Member.ReflectedType == typeof(T))
        return true;

    return HasAncestorOfType<T>(request.ParentRequest);
}
```

These bindings both work as intended (`IAuthenticationService` is bound to `FormsAuthenticationService` unless being injected into `MyWebApiController` in which case it is bound to `TokenAuthenticationService`). However, I'd like to create a factory binding like this so that `ICurrentCompany` gets bound to an object created from `IAuthentcationService`:

```
kernel.Bind<ICurrentCompany>().ToMethod(x => new Company { CompanyId = x.Kernel.Get<IAuthenticationService>().User.CompanyId});
```

This doesn't work. `IAuthenticationService` is always bound to `FormsAuthenticationService`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The reason why your solution is not working is simply that the `request.Target` cannot be controller because you are asking (requesting) the instance by "your self" - `kernel.Get<>()`*

I would make `Company` like this:

```
public class Company : ICurrentCompany{

     public int CompanyId { get; private set;}

     public class Company(IAuthenticationService authenticationService){
           this.CompanyId = authenticationService.User.CompanyId;
     }
}
```

and then simply bind:

```
kernel.Bind<ICurrentCompany>().To<Company>();
```

then the `request.Target` will  be the controller (at the root of the request hierarchy) and you will get the right service implementation.